# Android Radio Button

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a radio button group in Android which looks something like:

Choose Color:

- Red
- Blue
- Orange
- Green

I need to get selected radio button and also its value.

I have 4 radiobuttons in this manner within radiogroup `rg`

```
rb1a=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1a);
rb1b=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1b);
rb1c=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1c);
rb1d=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1d);
tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
next1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next1);
rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);

// I have error after this line.please help
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: How are your radiobuttons or UI defined?

Comment: Sanjeev, Don't forget to select an answer so we can close this question

Answer (score 5):

you can test the radion button with the **`isChecked()`** function.

for ex:

```
if(radio1_red.isChecked())
{
       txtView.setText("Red button is checked");
}
```

Have a look at this  [Example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/google-android-tutorial?page=0,4) .

You can also refer this  [Page - Form Stuff](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html)  given in android-sdk pages.

***Do this for getting selected radio button and also its value:***

```
 private OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on clicks
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
        Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

like you can see on the android documentation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html
the OnCheckedChangeListener has only the method
onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) and doesn't contain the method
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) -> remove it and try again.

You find an example here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html

regards